# Can not disable open_basedir restriction in php

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

I'm trying to disable `open_basedir` on my server.
I added:

`open_basedir = none` in php.ini

`php_admin_value open_basedir none` in httpd.conf

```
 <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/web>
                                Options FollowSymLinks
                                AllowOverride All
                                Order allow,deny
                                Allow from all
                                php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.vhost but my problem persist:

```
Warning: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in (...)
```

Ps. safe_mode is OFF. Any ideas?

Comment: `none` is not a special keyword in `php.ini`. What happens if you just remove the directive everywhere?

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in (...). Just checked my phinfo() and I see open_basedir /var/www/clients/client9/web16/web:/var/www/clients/client9/web16/tmp:/var/www/mysite.com/web:/srv/www/mysite.com/web:/usr/shar (...) but I'm unable to trace the file which I should to update in order to remove open_basedir :(

Comment: If you're trying to troubleshoot `open_basedir` I suggest you use `ini_get()` or `phpinfo(), rather that doing indirectly with curl. Any of them will tell you the exact value so you can (as last resource) do a file search.

Comment: phpinfo() will also tell you the `.ini` files loaded and whether it's a "Local Value" or "Master Value".

Answer (score 3):

just comment out open_basedir in php.ini.  It defaults to wide open if the directive is not found.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini: `;open_basedir =`. I have restared appache but the problem pesrist :(

Comment: File /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini is for php-cgi. If you use PHP as Apache module, you should edit another file (ex. /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini at my server)

Comment: In my php.ini I have:
Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d 
So, probably you need to check additional dir to